# Define default_url of username in user object (Django)

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a model for profile information. I want to set a default value in default_url with the username of that user. How could I do this?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    default_url = 'https://' + 'get_user_name_here' + '.' + settings.NETWORK_DOMAIN
    site_url = models.URLField(
        default=default_url,
        verbose_name='Site URL',
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have access to the `User` object through the `OneToOneField` so why get the `username` from there and make `default_url` it a property instead?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    site_url = models.URLField(
        default=default_url,
        verbose_name='Site URL',
    )

    @property
    def default_url(self):
        return 'https://{}.{}'.format(self.user.username, settings.NETWORK_DOMAIN)
```

Then you can access the the url like so:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=1)
default_url = profile.default_url
```

Comment: How do access it inside my UserProfile class?

Comment: Like any other variable on the model `self.default_url`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a create method as described in the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/)

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, user, other_attributes):
    user_profile = cls(url='https://'+user)
    # do something with the book
    return user_profile
```

Then, to create a UserProfile simply call your method:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.create("a_username", etc., ...)
```